# Can I get sheep to eat faster in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft: Pocket Edition, I have six red sheep and I need them to eat grass so they can grow back their wool again, but they only eat every 5 minutes.

Can I get them to eat quicker?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you need more wool, get more sheep.